# No se ve una imagen utilizando CoreUI y React

Tags: reactjs

No consigo que una imagen se vea correctamente en React utilizando la Free Bootstrap Admin Template de CoreUI.

Este es el código del componente donde quiero que se vea la imagen:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    CImage,
} from '@coreui/react';

const Asst = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <CImage rounded thumbnail src="../../assets/images/image.jpg" width={200} height={200} />
                <h1 style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>Titulo</h1>
            </div>

            <hr />

            { /* Resto del código */ }
        </>
    );
};

export default Asst;
```

La ruta completa de la imagen sería esta:

C:\proyecto\proyecto\src\assets\images\image.jpg

En la página se ve un cuadrado con bordes redondeados y dentro el típico icono de imagen rota. He comprobado la ruta y la extensión y parece estar correcto.

De momento todo lo tengo en local, no es una página funcional aún pero no sé cómo hacer para que se vea la imagen. He intentado también con el siguiente código:

```
<CImage rounded thumbnail src={require('../../assets/images/image.png').default} width={200} height={200} />
```

La única diferencia es que el icono de imagen rota no aparece y solo sale un recuadro en blanco de 200x200.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, Carga la imagen con un `import` primero y luego ya la consumes con curly braces `import myImage from '../../assets/images/image.png'`, luego `{myImage}`